# UDID replacement for iOS 8 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uniqueidentifier

I am searching for a UDID replacement for both iOS 7 and iOS 8, I took a look at MobileGestalt.h and I found the "DieID". This is readable without a jailbreak and on both iOS versions. The number is the same after I reinstalled the app. So I think its quite unique?

My question is is the "DieID" unique for all devices? And what exactly is the "DieID", I was not able to find anything about it.

Thanks, David

Comment: I am not sure but is it using any private api to get this, because if we use private api's then apple will not approve our app. https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/MobileGestalt/MobileGestalt.h

Comment: briefly, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Isn't this more of a hardware ID? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Hi, the app is an in-house application, so it won't be in the App Store

Comment: @holex Hi, The UUIDs or other ids are not unique for every device, they change after a reset, reboot or reinstallation of the app. I need a specific unique id for every device.

Comment: @Luke This is possible, do you think that the DieID is unique? It should be, right?

Comment: @DavidG., yes, they are not unique as the `UUID` was, but for privacy reason the developers cannot access to a _pure_ unique device ID legally.

Comment: @DavidG. I think it will be unique, but if it's what I linked to then maybe the ID would be the same for all dies cut from the same wafer of silicon. I'm no electronics expert - maybe ask on the SE site? :)

Comment: Generate a random UDID server side and it in user's keychain. If user deletes app and re install it you will find stored UDID.

Comment: @thierryb yeah, I already thought about it. But I am sure that the Keychain will be deleted after a Restore.

Comment: @DavidG Are you talking about fresh installation?

Comment: @thierryb I am talking about an iTunes iOS restore

Comment: So yes @DavidG you are right.

Answer (score 4):

The DieID is the baseband chip identifier and used in both the UDID process and the SHSH signing process (ECID / UniqueChipID).

It's likely only unique per chip manufacturer and obviously has a smaller namespace. The "UDID" is actually the SHA1 hexdigest of the serial number, ECID (DieID), wifi, and bluetooth mac addresses concatenated.

```rb
ecid = 17592186044415 #=> 0xFFFFFFFFFFF [DieID/UniqueChipID]
serial = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
bluetooth = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
wifi = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"

udid = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(serial + ecid.to_s + wifi + bluetooth)
#=> 26063df5d4741b7fe668d79e0263a1bc01af3e0a
```

Because of this, it's not as useful for device identification as it doesn't have as large of a namespace and requires use of private APIs; but it can be useful in certain enterprise contexts—e.g, a client held secret in an MDM enrollment process.

Comment: Wow, where did you get that info?

Comment: Mostly from jailbreaking ;)